# regexp easy pattern

Tags: php, regex, url

I have text :

```
Hello please click this:  
    https://active.gameta.com/VE?service=proservice&c=CMzc-53lyIbqVBCXzc62-YP64BM&hl=pl.  
    And follow the instructions if you have problems click
    http://problems.com/contact.php
```

i need this  https://active.gameta.com/VE?service=proservice&c=CMzc-53lyIbqVBCXzc62-YP64BM&hl=pl How? in regxp  in php

Comment: if (preg_match('%https://active\.gameta\.com/VE\?service=proservice&c=CMzc-53lyIbqVBCXzc62-YP64BM&hl=pl%', $subject, $regs)) {
 $result = $regs[0];
}

Comment: @FailedDev c= is changes

Comment: I am not really sure what you are asking. Do you want to transform textual links in actual HTML hyperlinks?

Comment: i have plain text and i need only  https://active.gameta.com/VE?service=proservice&c=CMzc-53lyIbqVBCXzc62-YP64BM&hl=pl but c= and &hl= could changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are millions of different regex's that would work because your question is super vague.  Please expand on what you have tried, what exactly you want to do (replace/search/etc).  But...

Here are a few that should match (may need to escape the `/` with `\/` depending on your situation):

```
https(.*)
https(.*)$
https:(.*)
https:(.*)$
https://(.*)
https://(.*)$
https://active\.gameta\.com/(.*)
https://active\.gameta\.com/(.*)$
etc...
```